# the anchor is not working fine inside the repeater

Tags: html, asp.net

I have a repeater and there is an anchor inside that but unfortunately the anchor has no effect when user click on the image button. in order to test I have added another anchor outside of repeater and it works fine but the one inside the repeater is not working.
Any comment is appreciated.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptrPlatforms" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptrPlatforms_ItemDataBound" OnItemCommand="rptrPlatforms_ItemCommand">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <a id="AnchorToBox"  href="#BoxSelectionPos" runat="server" style="text-decoration: none">
            <asp:ImageButton ID="imgPlatform" alt="" Style="" runat="server" OnCommand="Platform_Click" CommandName="PlatformClick" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PlatformLanguageID")+","+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PlatformID") %>' />
        </a>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

protected void rptrBoxes_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == (ListItemType.Item) || e.Item.ItemType == (ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
    {
        Image img = (Image)e.Item.FindControl("imgSetTopBox");
        img.ImageUrl = "/Pages/Shop-ProductSelection/images/" + drv.Row["Image1"].ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Inspect the generated html and see what's different...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the efforts to solve the problem were useless as the page scrolled to previous position even by using scrollto command in javascript. Finally I solved the problem by using the following source in code behind:

```
protected void Platform_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.CommandName == "PlatformClick")
   {
       ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "hash", "location.hash = '#BoxSelectionPos';", true);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to have the anchor tag, why not just use the ImageButton with OnClientClick?

```
 <asp:ImageButton  FID="imgPlatform" alt="" Style="" runat="server" OnCommand="Platform_Click" CommandName="PlatformClick" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PlatformLanguageID")+","+DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PlatformID") %>' 
                    OnClientClick="MyPage.aspx=#BoxSelectionPos" />
```

Comment: Thanks Rick, it is a nice shortcut, but unfortunately it is not working in my source code. I doubted about the OnCommand="Platform_Click" and commented it to make sure it may be the reason but it still doesn't work with that too.